# Enum types may not be instantiated error

Tags: java, arrays, enums, playing-cards

I am making a basic card deck at the moment and I've encountered a problem using enums.

How do I fix the following error(enum types may not be instantiated) in my code and get the value assigned to each enum

```
 public enum Rank {

    ACE(14),
    KING(13),
    QUEEN(12),
    JACK(11),
    TEN(10),
    NINE(9),
    EIGHT(8),
    SEVEN(7),
    SIX(6),
    FIVE(5),
    FOUR(4),
    THREE(3),
    TWO(2);
    private final int rankValue;

    Rank(int rankValue) {
        this.rankValue = rankValue;
    }

    public int getRankValue() {
        return rankValue;
    }

}
private Card[] cards = new Card[52];

public Deck() {
    int posInDeck = 0;
    for (Suit s : Suit.values()) {
        for (Rank r : Rank.values()) {
            cards[posInDeck] = new Card(s.toString(),new Rank(r.getRankValue(), r.toString()), false);// ERROR HERE
            posInDeck++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "How do I fix the following error" what error? Provide error message and **short but full** code will let us reproduce it. For now it looks like this code fragment is part of `Deck` class, but I can only assume it only on indentation levels and name of constructor.

Comment: Why not define only the values in your `Rank` enum and pass `Rank.ACE` to the constructor of your `Card` (and edit the field/getter/setter in `Card` accordingly ? Instantiating an enum doesn't make sense because an enum is a static set of values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't instantiate an `enum` like you would instantiate a `class`. The statement `new Rank(r.getRankValue(), r.toString())` is incorrect.

This is what you can do instead :

```
cards[posInDeck] = new Card(s.toString(),r,false);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `r` instead of `new Rank(r.getRankValue(), r.toString())`